# WordPress Theme redirects to the Index page - Theme customizer problem

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

I bought this WP Theme: [WP Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/primary-kids-and-school-wordpress-theme-education-material-design-wp/15900155)

I installed it on my webspace, everything worked.

Now I would like to customize it, but everytime I click on the customizer the theme redirects me back to the index page, is this a general issue or does this happens only on this theme?

Comment: can u plz explain your question more? need to see snapshots

Comment: I click on the customize button, see the classical customize page, where on the left are the tools (I see the page for 2 sec.) and then the redirect happens back to index.

Comment: why dont you contact their support, if you really bought this theme?

Comment: I will, I was curious whether this could be a general problem, but it seems to be something theme related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roman, opening the theme customizer should open the special theme customize option not to redirect to the index page.

You can check if this is theme problem if you set default WordPress theme for a moment and open the customizer from there. That theme should work well with the customizer.

If this is so, then you need to contact the theme support.

Else you have some configuration problems of another kind.